# FindBugs and annotations in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, findbugs, eclipse-jdt

I've tagged a method in my code with `javax.annotation.CheckForNull` and use it, without checking for `null`, in another place. When I run this code through FindBugs in Eclipse (via the plugin), there is no warning though.

Assuming there should be a warning (if not, what's a good test case?), why is it not showing?

It does show other warnings, not related to annotations.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you're looking for can be found in here: [Findbugs using jsr305 annotations in eclipse is not finding bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321873/findbugs-using-jsr305-annotations-in-eclipse-is-not-finding-bugs)

(try running findbugs outside of eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested (Windows, Eclipse Helios, latest plugin) and it worked, warning of possible dereferencing of a null variable.

Perhaps check if this warning is not deactivated in your settings.

[EDIT] Tested with both `javax.annotation.CheckForNull` and `edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.CheckForNull`, and both in the same class and in a class in a different package.

Comment: Almost all non-hidden detectors are activated, and those that aren't don't involve the annotations.